# ImapClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback vs ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: mailkit

Can I consider ImapClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback same? I mean same object (on behind scenes).

In my scenario, I have to collect URLs/values from message body and store in DB, these URLs are WebServices address, values are parameters to be used with WebService.
With all data collected, have to get response from WebServices

For email I HAVE to set ImapClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to accept any certificate.

On the other hand for some WebServices I can't bypass certificate validation, so ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback should not be set.

Right now, I'm setting and unsetting each like

```
????.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, k) True
...do whatetever I need....
????.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = nothing
```

This seems fine if working in sequence (Mail then WebService).
But what will happen if one user start to check mails and another user start to check URLs? Is there any chance one setting interfere on another?

Answer (score 0):

MailKit will use the callback that you assign to the ImapClient if non-null, and only fall back to ServicePointManager's callback if none is set on the ImapClient itself.

Comment: So ServicePointManager prevail if none is set in ImapClient.
Sorry for my ignorance.
If I set ImapClient, does ServicePointManager gets changed from any previous value set? If yes I´m in trouble......because at any point in time there will be a conflict

Comment: If you set a callback on the ImapClient, nothing gets set in the ServicePointManager, so you should be fine.

Comment: That is a relief, Thanks